# Why is my react state data undefined in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react 360 application using an API to fetch data and then display it on a panel. Below I have the following code:

```
export class CryptoControlInformation extends React.Component {


  state = {
    details: {
      description: '',
      links: [],
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const CRYPTO_CONTROL_PATH = 'https://cryptocontrol.io/api/v1/public/details/coin/bitcoin?key=some_key';
    fetch(CRYPTO_CONTROL_PATH)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {this.setState({
        details: {
          description: data["description"],
          links: [...this.state.details.links, ...data["links"] ]
      }})
    })
  }

  render() {
    let links = this.state.details.links;

    ##################################
    console.log(links[0])
    {_id: "5b41d21fa8a741cf4187ec60", type: "reddit", name: "r/Bitcoin Reddit", link: "https://reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/"}
    ####################################


    ####################################
    // Why is this returning undefined? 
    console.log(links[0]["name"]);
    ####################################

    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.rightHeader}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 40}}>Information</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.details.description}</Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.details.description}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I can't get the information inside my object and I don't understand why. I know that the information is there. I can console.log the object in its entirety but the individual pieces are undefined. What am I doing wrong? I've noticed in react that the state always has to be explicitly detailed.

For example, I found that I can't just do this:

```
export class Square extends React.Component {
  state = {
   info: undefined
  };

   componentDidMount() {

     // grab information (pseudocode)

     this.setState{info: data}
   }
}
```

I have to actually map out the data which is annoying:

```
export class Square extends React.Component {
  state = {
   info: {
     color: '',
     height: '',
     width: '',
   }
  };

   componentDidMount() {

     // grab information (pseudocode)

     this.setState{info: {
         color: data['red'],
         heigth: data['height'],
         width: data['width']
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I'm thinking that this has something to do with my problem. Am I on the right track?

Comment: You should not be accessing `this.state` values while setting the new state values. Try using the previous state values before using it to set it in the new state
`this.setState( prevState => {{details: {
          description: data["description"],
          links: [...prevState.details.links, ...data["links"] ]
      }}})`

@Dan Rubio

Answer (score 0):

Standard timing problem - you didn't look for 'react undefined', right?

When component loads data `render` is called (minimum) twice - once at initial mounting (w/o data) and 2nd time when data arrives (setState forces new render)

`console.log` (in chrome) cheats you silently updating earlier message

you can use `map` - it works fine with initially empty array - or check if value is ready in jsx

```
{!links.length && <Text>{links[0]["name"]}</Text/>}
```

... conditionally call rendering function, return `<Loading />` earlier, etc.

Using `setState` with function (Varun's comment) isn't required, it's safer (for some cases) but not obligatory